# Webscrape LinkedIn Names

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

My code will get to the search page of LinkedIn (after entering a username and pass)

But what is the code to scrape a users name once on this page?

Eg-

John Smith

Bradley Cooper

etc..

Here is my code so far

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
productlinks=[]
test1=[]

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


url = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?currentCompany=%5B%221252860%22%5D&geoUrn=%5B%22103644278%22%5D&keywords=sales&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&page=2"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-email')
username.send_keys('example123@gmail.com')
password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-password')

password.send_keys('Password123')
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-submit')
log_in_button.click()
```

Comment: You need to locate the search box. `send_keys` the name you want to search. Then see where the names are located in the HTML to scrape them.

Comment: I need to sign in first, my sign in does not work

Comment: ..simply find the `sign-in` button and click it after sending username and password through beautifulsoup